# White area at the bottom of my webpage when i try to create a responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my webpage responsive to fit on an ipad and mobile, as i adjust my media query, i noticed this white area at the bottom, the body element when highlighted, it doesnt reach that area, so i dont know where it came from, anyhelp would be appreaciated. thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTZHe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30b0c.png)

```css
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    
}



div.logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(147, 235, 238);
}

div.navi {
    
    background-color: rgb(228, 226, 217);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

p {
    color: rgb(97, 87, 226);
}

.para2{
    color: black;
}
p.nav {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-style: solid;


}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(97, 87, 226);
}

img {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    
}

/* inner body styling */


div.inner-body {
    background-image: url(image/book2.png); 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
    
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    left:1000px;
    left: 338px;
    font-size: 30px;
    
}

.para {
    
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left:345px;
    top:74px;
    background-color: rgb(206, 200, 180);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

form {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: fit-content;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left:350px;
    top:100px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 239, 228);
}

.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.error1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.navi2 {
    
    width: fit-content;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 600px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top:300px;
}

.user-links {
    position: relative;
    left:20px;
    bottom:30px;
}

.user-links:link{
    color: brown;
}

.userlogo {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 100px;
}


.btn {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}







/* footer styling */

.emaillogo, .telelogo {
    width: 20px;
}
div.foot {
    
    background-color: brown;
}
footer{
    background-color: rgb(126, 226, 230);
    height: 200px;
}

.footimage {
    width: 400px;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 0;
}
div.contact{
    width: fit-content;
    height: 200px;
    height: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 185px;
    font-size: 12px;

}

.usefullinks {
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left:750px;
    bottom:280px;
height: fit-content;
}

.connect {
    width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px ;
    bottom: 400px;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: fit-content;
}

.fb, .tw, .yt, .ln {
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
   
}

/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width:915px) {


    div.logo {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgb(147, 235, 238);
    }
    .content{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        
    }
  

    div.inner-body {
        background-image: url(image/book2.png); 
        
        border-style: solid;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
        width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      
    }

    div.navi {
        width: 980px;
        font-size: 30px;
       
        padding-bottom: 90px;
    }
    .inner-body {
        width: 100%;
       
    }


    

    .header{
        left:50px;
    }

    .para{
        width: 700px;
        display: block;
        left: 25px;
        font-size: 35px;
        padding:30px;
        top:20px;
    }

    form {
        width: 600px;
        left: 60px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .navi2 {

        display: none;
    }

    .usefullinks{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .connect{
        display: none;
    }

    .contact {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:415px) {
    .content{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {  
        margin: 0;
    }
    .inner-body {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="log-it-reports.css">
    <script src="log-it-reports.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class= "content">
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="image/logo1.png" alt="Academy Logo" >
        </div>
        <div class="navi">
            <p id="nav"> 
                <a href="homepage.html" title=" Home Page"> Home</a> |
                <a href="academics.html" title=" Academics Page">Academics</a> |
                <a href="services.html" title=" Services">Services</a> |
                <a href="covid-19.html" title=" Covid-19 Page">Covid-19</a> | 
                <a href="students&parents.html" title=" Students&Parents Page">Students & Parents</a> |
                <a href="Transcripts.html" title="Transcripts Page">Transcripts</a>  |
                <a href="staff.html" title="Staff Page">Staff</a> |
                <a href="career.html" title="Career Available">Career</a> |
                <a href="events" title="Events Page">Events</a> | 
                <a href="studentaccount.html" title="Student Account">Student Account</a> |
        </p>
        </div>
       <div class="inner-body">
           <div class = "header" >
            <h1>Steps For IT-Issues Logging:</h1>
           </div>
       
       <div class="para">
           <p class="para2">Please read the following instructions before submitting a report:</p> 
           <ol>
               <li>Fill out all of the fields.</li>
               <li>Use a valid email.</li>
               <li>Select a problem type.</li>
               <li>Be as detailed as possible so that the IT staff could address the issue properly (100 characters minumum).</li>
               <li>Normally most issues get addressed within 2 hours, please be patient.</li>
           </ol>
       </div>
       <div class="form1">
        <form  method="GET" onsubmit=" return formValidations() " action="log-it-reports.html"><br>
          <div class="error1" id= "errorMsg"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="subject"><b>Subject:</label> 
          <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject Title"  > 
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg2"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="email"><b>Email:</label> 
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="staff@wearview.com">  
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg3"></div>
          <div>
            <select name="techtype" id="problemtypes">
                <option value="">Problem Type</option>
                <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg4"></div>
          <div>
          <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description goes here" name="descript" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
          </div>          
          
          <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="notify" name="notify" value="">
            <label for="notify">Inform me by email when issue is resolved.</label> 
        </div>
        </form>
       </div>
       <div class="navi2">
           <div class="userimage">
               <img class="userlogo" src="image/userlogo.png" alt="User Image">
           </div>
           <div class="user-links">
               <navi>
                <a class="staffname" href="staffname.html" title=" Staff Name">Staff Name</a> <br><br>
                <a href="inbox.html" title=" User Inbox">Inbox</a> <br><br>
                <a href="notifications.html" title="Notifications">Notifications</a> <br><br>
                <a href="files.html" title="Files">Files</a> <br><br>
                <a href="settings.html" title="Settings">Settings</a> <br><br>
                <a href="help.html" title="Help">Help</a>  <br><br>
                <a href="qr-for-mobile.html" title="QR for Mobile">QR For Mobile</a> <br><br>
                <a href="logout.html" title="Log Out">Log Out</a> 
               </navi>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
       <div class="foot">
           <footer id = "footy">
           <div>
            <img class="footimage" src="image/logo1.png" alt="Academy Logo"  width="400px">
           </div>
           <div class="contact">
               <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                <p><img class="emaillogo" src="image/email (2).png" alt="emaillogo"> :wearview_academy@wearview.com</p>
              <p><img class="telelogo" src="image/tele.png" alt="telelogo"> :+2499100000000</p>
           </div>
           <div class="usefullinks">
            <h3>Useful Links</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="career.html" title=" Jobs Available">Career</a></li> 
                <li><a href="websiteerror.html" title=" Report A Website Issue">Report A Website Issue</a></li> 
                <li><a href="aboutus.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="covid-19.html" title="Covid-19">Covid-19</a></li>
                <li><a href="events" title=" FAQs Page">Events</a></li>
            </ul>  
           </div>
           <div class="connect">
            <h3>Connect With Us </h3><br>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title= "facebook"><img class="fb" src="image/fb.png" alt = "Facebook" /></a>     
                <a href="https://www.twitter.com" title= "twitter"><img class="tw" src="image/tw.jpg" alt = "Twitter" /></a>      
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com" title= "youtube"><img class="yt" src="image/you.png" alt = "Youtube" /></a>      
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" title= "linkedin"><img class="ln" src="image/linkd.png" alt = "LinkedIn" /></a>     
           </div>
           </footer>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to set the body width to 100vw (100% of viewport width) and also I highly recommend NOT to use pixel values (use relative values like %, em, vw/vh), especially when you want to develop responsive webpages

Answer (score 0):

Because of the default browser stylesheet, the body has a `margin` set. You can remove it with the following CSS reset:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, your `.content` has a margin set to `10px`, which adds space to the bottom, remove it when you don't want it or only apply it to the top, right and left using:

```css
margin: 10px 10px 0 10px
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="log-it-reports.css">
    <script src="log-it-reports.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 0
        }

        .content {
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;

        }



        div.logo {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: rgb(147, 235, 238);
        }

        div.navi {

            background-color: rgb(228, 226, 217);
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 19px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            padding-top: 1px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
        }

        p {
            color: rgb(97, 87, 226);
        }

        .para2 {
            color: black;
        }

        p.nav {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 5px;
            border-style: solid;


        }

        a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: rgb(97, 87, 226);
        }

        img {
            margin-left: 20px;
            width: 400px;

        }

        /* inner body styling */


        div.inner-body {
            background-image: url(image/book2.png);
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            max-width: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            margin-top: 20px;
            height: 1200px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .header {

            width: 700px;
            position: relative;
            left: 1000px;
            left: 338px;
            font-size: 30px;

        }

        .para {

            width: 800px;
            position: relative;
            left: 345px;
            top: 74px;
            background-color: rgb(206, 200, 180);
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            border-radius: 20px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        form {
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            width: fit-content;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            left: 350px;
            top: 100px;
            background-color: rgb(240, 239, 228);
        }

        .error {
            color: red;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        .error1 {
            color: red;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        .navi2 {

            width: fit-content;
            width: 300px;
            height: 600px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 600px;
            background-color: cadetblue;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            top: 300px;
        }

        .user-links {
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            bottom: 30px;
        }

        .user-links:link {
            color: brown;
        }

        .userlogo {
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 100px;
            position: relative;
            left: 30px;
            bottom: 100px;
        }


        .btn {
            width: 100px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }







        /* footer styling */

        .emaillogo,
        .telelogo {
            width: 20px;
        }

        div.foot {

            background-color: brown;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: rgb(126, 226, 230);
            /* height: 200px; */
        }

        .footimage {
            width: 400px;
            height: fit-content;
            margin: 0;
        }

        div.contact {
            width: fit-content;
            height: 200px;
            height: fit-content;
            position: relative;
            left: 400px;
            bottom: 185px;
            font-size: 12px;

        }

        .usefullinks {
            width: fit-content;
            font-size: 12px;
            position: relative;
            left: 750px;
            bottom: 280px;
            height: fit-content;
        }

        .connect {
            width: fit-content;
            position: relative;
            left: 1000px;
            bottom: 400px;
            font-size: 12px;
            height: fit-content;
        }

        .fb,
        .tw,
        .yt,
        .ln {
            width: 50px;
            border-radius: 10px;

        }

        /* Media Queries */

        @media screen and (max-width:915px) {


            div.logo {
                width: 100%;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: rgb(147, 235, 238);
            }

            .content {
                width: 100%;
                /* margin: 10px; */
                padding: 0;

            }


            div.inner-body {
                background-image: url(image/book2.png);

                border-style: solid;
                margin-top: 15px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;

            }

            div.navi {
                width: 980px;
                font-size: 30px;

                padding-bottom: 90px;
            }

            .inner-body {
                width: 100%;

            }




            .header {
                left: 50px;
            }

            .para {
                width: 700px;
                display: block;
                left: 25px;
                font-size: 35px;
                padding: 30px;
                top: 20px;
            }

            form {
                width: 600px;
                left: 60px;
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            .navi2 {

                display: none;
            }

            .usefullinks {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .connect {
                display: none;
            }

            .contact {
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:415px) {
            .content {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .inner-body {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="image/logo1.png" alt="Academy Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="navi">
            <p id="nav">
                <a href="homepage.html" title=" Home Page"> Home</a> |
                <a href="academics.html" title=" Academics Page">Academics</a> |
                <a href="services.html" title=" Services">Services</a> |
                <a href="covid-19.html" title=" Covid-19 Page">Covid-19</a> |
                <a href="students&parents.html" title=" Students&Parents Page">Students & Parents</a> |
                <a href="Transcripts.html" title="Transcripts Page">Transcripts</a> |
                <a href="staff.html" title="Staff Page">Staff</a> |
                <a href="career.html" title="Career Available">Career</a> |
                <a href="events" title="Events Page">Events</a> |
                <a href="studentaccount.html" title="Student Account">Student Account</a> |
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-body">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Steps For IT-Issues Logging:</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="para">
                <p class="para2">Please read the following instructions before submitting a report:</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>Fill out all of the fields.</li>
                    <li>Use a valid email.</li>
                    <li>Select a problem type.</li>
                    <li>Be as detailed as possible so that the IT staff could address the issue properly (100 characters
                        minumum).</li>
                    <li>Normally most issues get addressed within 2 hours, please be patient.</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="form1">
                <form method="GET" onsubmit=" return formValidations() " action="log-it-reports.html"><br>
                    <div class="error1" id="errorMsg"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="subject"><b>Subject:</label>
                        <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject Title">
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="error" id="errorMsg2"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="email"><b>Email:</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="staff@wearview.com">
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="error" id="errorMsg3"></div>
                    <div>
                        <select name="techtype" id="problemtypes">
                            <option value="">Problem Type</option>
                            <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                            <option value="Software">Software</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="error" id="errorMsg4"></div>
                    <div>
                        <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description goes here" name="descript" rows="15"
                            cols="50"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="notify" name="notify" value="">
                        <label for="notify">Inform me by email when issue is resolved.</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="navi2">
                <div class="userimage">
                    <img class="userlogo" src="image/userlogo.png" alt="User Image">
                </div>
                <div class="user-links">
                    <navi>
                        <a class="staffname" href="staffname.html" title=" Staff Name">Staff Name</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="inbox.html" title=" User Inbox">Inbox</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="notifications.html" title="Notifications">Notifications</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="files.html" title="Files">Files</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="settings.html" title="Settings">Settings</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="help.html" title="Help">Help</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="qr-for-mobile.html" title="QR for Mobile">QR For Mobile</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="logout.html" title="Log Out">Log Out</a>
                    </navi>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot">
            <footer id="footy">
                <div>
                    <img class="footimage" src="image/logo1.png" alt="Academy Logo" width="400px">
                </div>
                <div class="contact">
                    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                    <p><img class="emaillogo" src="image/email (2).png" alt="emaillogo"> :wearview_academy@wearview.com
                    </p>
                    <p><img class="telelogo" src="image/tele.png" alt="telelogo"> :+2499100000000</p>
                </div>
                <div class="usefullinks">
                    <h3>Useful Links</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="career.html" title=" Jobs Available">Career</a></li>
                        <li><a href="websiteerror.html" title=" Report A Website Issue">Report A Website Issue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="covid-19.html" title="Covid-19">Covid-19</a></li>
                        <li><a href="events" title=" FAQs Page">Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="connect">
                    <h3>Connect With Us </h3><br>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="facebook"><img class="fb" src="image/fb.png"
                            alt="Facebook" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com" title="twitter"><img class="tw" src="image/tw.jpg"
                            alt="Twitter" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="youtube"><img class="yt" src="image/you.png"
                            alt="Youtube" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" title="linkedin"><img class="ln" src="image/linkd.png"
                            alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that I also removed the height of the footer in the example above, since it causes some spacing as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help David, i could see that the white spaces is not there anymore in the ipad version but instead, it was filled with the footer background color, but i dont want the footer be that big in terms of height, i wanted it smaller, and using the height:200px would bring back the white space , what do you think is the alternative ?

Comment: @ArcanePersona Can you add a screenshot/illustration of your desired output to your question? So we have an idea of what you are trying to achieve in greater detail.

Comment: i added a second screenshot showing a grey background while you can see the body content is squeezed to the left, i want it to fill that grey area too.

Comment: @ArcanePersona try to set the body width to 100vw; this should fill the body to 100% of the viewport width

Comment: i tested it now but unfortunately the width didn't change, something is stopping it , i cant locate it :/